# GHCI needlessly recompiles sub-package

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, ghci, haskell-language-server

I have a project (let's call it parent) that has a sub-package (child). Using HLS from emacs, whenever I change a file in the parent that imports part of the child package, and try to load it, GHCI will recompile the whole sub-package again every time. The sub-package has lots of TH code in it and takes a long time to compile, which really messes with your workflow when you just want to check if something works. Any ideas?

I'm using

- stack 2.7.5 with resolver lts-18.28
- cabal 3.6.2.0
- GHC   8.10.7
- HLS   1.7.0.0

My `stack.yaml` in the parent package:

```yaml
resolver: lts-18.28

packages:
- .
- sub-package

extra-deps:
- ... (omitted)

allow-newer: true
```

EDIT: Minimal example: [git repo](https://github.com/farzadbekran/ghci-test)

file details:

parent `stack.yaml`

```yaml
resolver: lts-18.28

packages:
- .
- child
```

child `stack.yaml`

```yaml
resolver: lts-18.28

packages:
- .
```

parent main `src/Parent.hs`:

```hs
module Parent where

import Child

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = childFunc
```

child main file `child/src/Child.hs`:

```hs
module Child where

childFunc :: IO ()
childFunc = putStrLn "someFunc"
```

Comment: Please try to make a [MCVE] of this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout OK I'll try. Might take a while though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Done. Didn't even need to use any TH code. Changing the `Parent.hs` file and loading it via `C-c C-l` in emacs causes it to recompile `Child.hs`.

Comment: seems like it has nothing to do with emacs and/or lsp, as this happens with simple `stack ghci` too. just `:load src/Parent.hs` does the same too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out adding `-fobject-code` to the `.ghci` file causes ghci to create object files, which in turn saves it the trouble of recompiling everything every time.

[GHC reference](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html?highlight=flag%20reference#code-generation-options)

Comment: The default in GHCi is `-fbyte-code`, not `-fno-code`.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn so if it was generating byte code, shouldn't it have skipped the already compiled files on recompile? unless byte code does not behave as I'm expecting?

Comment: Recompilation checking in it’s own is a complicated matter, and it gets worse in the presence of TH, so I don’t claim I understand the reason for behavior you observed, I just didn’t want someone reading this to be confused with no-code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this handshakes with HLS, but when you run `stack ghci`, by default it loads modules from all packages in the project into GHCi, all in an interpreted form, which means recompiling `Child.hs` every time GHCi starts.

However, if you specify the parent package (here, named `ghci-test`) on the command line: `stack ghci ghci-test`, it will only load modules from that package and use the compiled version of `child` (which it will build, if necessary, prior to switching over to the GHCi prompt).

Some caveats:

- You will not be able to load anything from the child package into this GHCi session (e.g., `:l Child` will fail).
- Changes to the `child` package won't take effect unless you quit and restart GHCi.

Comment: passing the module name to ghci indeed fixes the recompile issue, but the caveats you mentioned are not what I need in this case, since the sub-package is evolving along with the parent and changes happen to both packages at the same time. if I wanted to get that behavior, the easier way would be to move the `child` dependency in the `stack.yaml` from `packages` section to `extra-deps` section.